# How to send multiple bundles from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

i want to send multiple bundles from activity to fragment, the problem i'm facing here is bundle 2 get the reference of bundle 1, how to differentiate both the bundles. please provide me some suggestion.

Here is what i pass from activity to fragment,

```
FeatureTab featureTab = new FeatureTab();
featureTab.setArguments(bundle_DescriptioneTab);
featureTab.setArguments(bundle_User_Review);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tabcontainer, featureTab, "FeatureTab");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here is what i used in fragments to get the bundle,

**Bundle 1 :**

```
 private void setDescription() {
    try {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        txt_Description.setText(bundle.getString("long_description"));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        AppUtils.logError(TAG, "NullPointerException");
    }
}
```

**Bundle 2:**

```
private void getUserReviewsParcel() {
    try {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        UserReviewsParcel userReviewsParcel = bundle.getParcelable("user_reviews");
        List<UserReviewsBean> list = userReviewsParcel.getparcelList();

        // set the listview adapter
        setListviewAdapter(list);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        AppUtils.logError(TAG, "NullPointerException");
    }
}
```

i'm calling both the methods in onCreateView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to send multiple bundles from activity to fragment

Use [Bundle.putBundle(KEY,VALUE)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to prepare a bundle which contains other bundles and you can access using keys:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putBundle("bundle_DescriptioneTab",bundle_DescriptioneTab);
bundle.putBundle("bundle_User_Review",bundle_User_Review);
```

Pass `bundle` to `setArguments` method and you can access both Bundle using `bundle_DescriptioneTab` and `bundle_User_Review` keys.

Comment: Sounds good, hope it will solve my problem, thanks for your help.